# Getting console spam in Xcode when using Vision framework and face moves off screen

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, debugging, apple-vision

I am running a face detector with the **Vision** framework, but have encountered one item that is making debugging a challenge.

When I move a face off screen, I will often be spammed with the following error in the console:

> LandmarkDetector error -20:out of bounds in int
>   vision::mod::LandmarkAttributes::computeBlinkFunction(const
>   vImage_Buffer &, const Geometry2D_rect2D &, const
>   std::vector &, vImage_Buffer &, vImage_Buffer &,
>   std::vector &, std::vector &) @
>   /BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/Vision/Vision-2.0.62/LandmarkDetector/LandmarkDetector_Attributes.mm:535

I understand that this error is within the framework, and has no impact on my application. However, I am also monitoring other data in the console and having numerous, large errors fly by makes that difficult.

My hope is that there is a way to disable this specific item. Thus far, I have not found anything that works.

This occurs with Xcode 10.1, targeting iOS 12.1 on multiple devices.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By going to **Product** > **Scheme** > **Edit Scheme**, and applying the following setting, I got rid of the spam.

[image]